# Disable the loading overlay in SSRS

Tags: reporting-services

I have an SSRS report that auto refreshes every minute that is going to be used as a real time dashboard for my company. The caveat is that it has around a 2-3 second loading screen when it refreshes. Now, since there is no need to inform the user that it's refreshing when it will just be constantly running on a flatscreen I desperately want to find a way to disable it.

I'm accessing the report on firefox if that makes any difference.

Any ideas?

Comment: You could use some java script to automatically suppress the loading pop up, also have you looked into Power BI. It's ideal for what you want and ssrs reports can be uploaded to it.

Comment: How do you import SSRS reports into Power BI?

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/reporting-services/pin-reporting-services-items-to-power-bi-dashboards